# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when using Google ACRA

Tags: java, android, logging, ssl

I use Google ACRA in my application.

Recently I get the following error sent to my report file:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:213)
    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImplWrapper.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImplWrapper.java:35)
    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:92)
    at org.acra.util.FakeSocketFactory.createSocket(FakeSocketFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.sendPost(HttpRequest.java:109)
    at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.sendPost(HttpRequest.java:80)
    at org.acra.util.HttpUtils.doPost(HttpUtils.java:59)
    at org.acra.sender.GoogleFormSender.send(GoogleFormSender.java:62)
    at org.acra.ErrorReporter.sendCrashReport(ErrorReporter.java:850)
    at org.acra.ErrorReporter.checkAndSendReports(ErrorReporter.java:960)
    at org.acra.ErrorReporter$ReportsSenderWorker.run(ErrorReporter.java:142)
```

The error occurs only on Nexus S running Android 2.3.7. 
I Can't tell if its always the same device.

Clearly the error is not from the application itself, but from Google reports.

Does anyone have an idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you use ProGuard as well?

Answer (score 1):

Are you obfuscating?..I had similar problems but could fix them.

If so, try adding these lines to your proguard.cfg:

```
#ACRA specifics
# we need line numbers in our stack traces otherwise they are pretty useless
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# ACRA needs "annotations" so add this... 
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# keep this class so that logging will show 'ACRA' and not a obfuscated name like 'a'.
# Note: if you are removing log messages elsewhere in this file then this isn't necessary
-keep class org.acra.ACRA {
        *;
}

# keep this around for some enums that ACRA needs
-keep class org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode {
   *;
}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
public void addCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
public org.acra.ErrorReporter$ReportsSenderWorker handleSilentException(java.lang.Throwable);
}
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your Nexus has all the libraries required? Are you sure the version of the libraries are the same as in other phones or the emulator?

Comment: No, I'm not. I see this error on Google report, I don't have access the actual device. My application is on the market, so I know that hundreds of people use it, but the error comes only from Nexus S, I'm not sure if it's one device or different Nexus S devices.